# Flex - ArrayCollection - adding and removing a filterFunction

Tags: flash, apache-flex, refresh, arraycollection, filterfunction

I am using Adobe Flash Builder 4 Premium. I have a `mx:DataGrid` and a `s:TextInput`, and I am trying to set up a search box that filters the DataGrid on each key press.

[This page](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_to_ArrayCollection_s_filterFunction-5441.html) shows a nearly perfect example of what I'm trying to do, except that I'm setting this up in a `s:TitleWindow`, which is brought up as a popup using the PopUpManager. The list I'm trying to filter can be very large. It is a list of usernames, fetched from a MySQL database via PHP. Since it can be so large, I want the list to be populated once in the main application and then referenced in the popup window so that it doesn't have to fetch all the usernames each time the user opens the popup.

I have all of this working fine for the first time you bring up the popup, but if you close it and bring it up again, I get this runtime error:

[image: Flash runtime error]

I also get this error if I attempt to set the `filterFunction` back to null just before closing the popup.

See sample code below:

**Main Application:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.*;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            [Bindable] public var allMembersList:ArrayCollection;

            private function openPopup():void
            {
                var popupInstance:popup = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this as DisplayObject, popup, true) as popup;
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popupInstance);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button label="Open Popup" click="openPopup()"/>
</s:Application>
```

**Popup:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:model="services.model.*"
               tabChildren="false"
               close="close()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            private function getUsers(startsWith:String = ""):void
            {
                if (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList == null)
                {
                    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList = new ArrayCollection();
                    getUsersResult.token = php.getUsers();
                }

                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList.filterFunction = function(item:Object):Boolean
                {
                    return item.username.match(new RegExp("^"+ startsWith, "i"));
                };
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList.refresh();
                grdMemberList.dataProvider = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList;
            }

            private function getUsersResultHandler():void
            {
                var users:Object = getUsersResult.lastResult;
                for each (var user:Object in users)
                    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList.addItem({"username":user.username});
            }

            private function close():void
            {
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList.filterFunction = null;
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.allMembersList.refresh();
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <model:MODEL id="php" fault="{Alert.show('There was a PHP error!\nPlease note the steps taken to produce this error and call support.\n\nError Message: '+ event.fault.faultDetail, 'Error');}" showBusyCursor="false"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="getUsersResult" result="getUsersResultHandler()"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:DataGrid id="grdMemberList" creationComplete="getUsers()">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Member List" dataField="username"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    <s:TextInput id="txtUsername" keyUp="{ if (event.charCode != 13 && event.charCode != 0) getUsers(txtUsername.text); }"/>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

The app still seems to work as expected, despite the error, but I'm not a fan of having errors in my app, so I would really like to figure out what is causing this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: The code I posted is a small excerpt from my app that I hadn't tested before posting it. It doesn't look like it produces that error for me. I will keep going through my code to see if I can narrow it down, but in the meantime, if anyone has any insight based on just the error message alone, I would love to hear it.

Comment: None of the items in that call stack refers to an array collection its all about display objects and the final one is it trying to hide something. I think it might have something to do with the call close="close()". One thought I have is the popup is removed from stage before the call back is run.

Comment: Run your code in debug mode to figure out exactly what is throwing the error.  Also, it may be beneficial for you to post the full stack trace instead of a screen shot of it.

Comment: I'm still baffled by this, but it looks like the problem was that I had the property tabChildren set to false for the TitleWindow. I do this so that I can control the tabbing functionality myself without the default behavior of tabbing. Now that I looked at it closer, the documentation says not to use tabChildren in Flex, but to use hasFocusableChildren instead (which doesn't work). Not sure why this problem only showed itself when I started setting up the above scenario, but does anyone have a way for me to disable the default TAB key behavior so that I can set it up myself?

Comment: Could you try capturing the keydown or keyup event and then calling the preventDefault() method to do this?  Another thought, since I've heard of the tab key specific issues, would be to call the setFocus() function just after the keydown is captured to prevent the focus from being being changed before you are able to prevent default functionality.

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, that was pretty much the answer. They actually have a property on the TitleWindow called keyFocusChange, which is exactly what I want to prevent, so I just set keyFocusChange="{ event.preventDefault(); }" and then I set up my own keyDown event to listen for the TAB key and change the focus appropriately. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with the `tabChildren` property. The documentation says not to use this property in Flex, but to use `hasFocusableChildren` instead. Not sure why this problem only showed itself once I was trying to set the `filterFunction`.

The reason I was setting `tabChildren` to false was so that the default TAB key functionality (switching focus) would not take place, so that I can control that behavior myself. The `hasFocusableChildren` property doesn't work (or at least, setting it to false doesn't stop the TAB key from switching focus), so I may need to try another means of capturing the TAB key event and stopping it.

---

**EDIT:**

For any that are interested (even though it doesn't really have anything to do with the original post), the solution was to change:

```
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:model="services.model.*"
               width="1000"
               height="550"
               tabChildren="false"
               close="close()">
```

to:

```
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:model="services.model.*"
               width="1000"
               height="550"
               keyFocusChange="{ event.preventDefault(); }"
               close="close()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I never try testing your code (because it needs server-side also) but I think you should not set filterFunction back to null. Alternatively, you could set it to a function that always returns true.

```
function defaultFilterFunc( item: Object ): Boolean { return true; }
```